# Error in arm template for assigning policy

Tags: azure-resource-manager

Getting error when deploying arm template for assigning policy "SSH access from the Internet should be blocked". I am taking the parameters from Azure portal but still getting error for field.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zda2h.png)

Comment: are you trying to use a template to assign a policy or create a policy definition?  can you share the template...

Comment: Could you please provide your arm template?